# I can't access the initial state of my useState hook inside of my method to change the state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some saved data that I want to add to a chartjs chart. I am using a useState hook to change the initial state of the data for the chart by mapping through my saved data and pushing that data to the empty 'data' array inside of my initial state.

```
const [chartData, setData] = useState({
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My Overall Progress',
        data: [],
        fill: true,
        borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
    ],
  });


  // Push Data Method
  const pushChartData = () => {
    console.log(chartData.datasets[0].data);
    console.log(games);
    setData(games.map((game) => chartData.datasets[0].data.push(game.score)));
  };

  pushChartData();
```

I keep getting an error that reads:

```
TypeError: chartData.datasets is undefined
```

However, the console.log for chartData.datasets[0].data logs what I need in the console. As well as the console.log for games.

I am not sure if this is a scope issue or not.

> Here is my whole component:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Line } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import { getGames } from '../../actions/game';

const GamesLineChart = ({ getGames, game: { games } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getGames();
  }, [getGames]);

  const chartData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
      {
        label: 'My Overall Progress',
        data: (games || []).map(({ score }) => score),
        fill: true,
        borderColor: 'rgb(0,0,0)',
        tension: 0.1,
      },
    ],
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div
        className='allGameChart'
        style={{ position: 'relative', height: '40vh', width: '45vw' }}
      >
        <Line data={chartData} options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false }} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

GamesLineChart.propTypes = {
  getGames: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  game: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  game: state.game,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getGames })(GamesLineChart);
```

> UPDATE:

> I console.log 'chartData' and this is what I see in the console:

```
Object { labels: [], datasets: (1) […] }
​
   datasets: Array [ {…} ]
​​
     0: Object { label: "My Overall Progress", fill: true,borderColor:"rgb(0,0,0)", … }
​​​
      borderColor: "rgb(0,0,0)"
​​​
      data: Array(7) [ 170, 125, 7, … ]
​​​​
       0: 170
​​​​
       1: 125
​​​​
       2: 7
​​​​
       3: 100
​​​​
       4: 100
​​​​
       5: 5
​​​​
       6: 200
​​​​
       length: 7
​​​​
       <prototype>: Array []
​​​
     fill: true
​​​
     label: "My Overall Progress"
​​​
     tension: 0.1
​​​
     <prototype>: Object { … }
​​
   length: 1
​​
   <prototype>: Array []
​
labels: Array []
​
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

> So I can see my scores, but the chart in the DOM is not populating the scores...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you called setData function, you passed an array instead of an object, so you replaced your **object** with an **array**, in the second execution of the function, it tried to access your property **chartData.datasets** that is undefined, and it read an item of an array that is **undefined**, this is why you have the error.

```
 const chartData = {
    labels: (games || []).map(({score}, i) => "label " + (i+1)),
    datasets: [
       {
         label: 'My Overall Progress',
         // I only have the || [] here in case `games` isn't already an array as default state
         data: (games || []).map(({score}) => score).reverse(),
         fill: true,
         borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
         tension: 0.1,         
       }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's the thing `state` is for something your component **owns** - your component doesn't **own** `games`, redux does, therefore it is not part of your component's state. Don't try to make it part of your state. As a matter of fact, your component doesn't (shouldn't) even have state.

This is what your component should look like:

```
const GamesLineChart = ({ getGames, game: { games } }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getGames();
  }, [getGames]);

  const chartData = {
    labels: [],
    datasets: [
       {
         label: 'My Overall Progress',
         // I only have the || [] here in case `games` isn't already an array as default state
         data: (games || []).map(({score}) => score),
         fill: true,
         borderColor: 'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
         tension: 0.1,         
       }
    ]
  }

  return (
    <Fragment>
      <div>
        <div
          className='allGameChart'
          style={{ position: 'relative', height: '40vh', width: '45vw' }}
        >
          <Line data={chartData} options={{ maintainAspectRatio: false }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};
```

Comment: games is an array of saved games that I passed into the component as a prop like so:

`const GamesLineChart = ({ game: { games } }) => {`

games is an array of games saved by the user. The individual indices of games are objects that contain: score, strikes, spares, openFrames, _id, user, and date. 

games[0]: 
`{ score: x, strikes: x, spares: x, openFrames: x, _id: "x", user: "x", date: "x" }`

Comment: where does 'existing' come from?

Comment: I tried your solution and now I'm getting a new error: **Error: Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.**

Comment: @melly18 That's because you are calling `pushChartData` every time your component renders and you are updating state every time you call `pushChartData` (which causees a re-render). Post your whole component code.

Comment: whole component posted!

Comment: @melly18 - see the edit, your component shouldn't even have state.

Comment: I followed your comment for my component. There are no more errors, but the line chart is not generating a line to reflect the scores.

Comment: @melly18 - post your code. Do games get requested and populated into `chartData`?

Comment: update posted. I posted the whole component and what I can see in the console. I do see the scores being populated inside chartData in the console but the chart in the DOM is not populating the scores.

Comment: Your chart in order to work it needs some labels like data :
https://github.com/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/blob/master/example/src/charts/Line.js
See my answer.

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil thank you! I'm seeing scores displayed on the chart now. Is there a way for me to reverse the array order? My games array is set up to where the most recent game will be first, so my line chart is read right to left instead of left to right...

Comment: @SoufianeBoutahlil thanks a lot for your help. This makes much more sense now.